# Extracting like count instagram-post using Python

Tags: python, instagram

I am trying to get the like count from someone's latest posts (and also get the Instagram link for that post) using Python but I can't seem to figure it out. I have tried every single method that is used online but none of them seem to work anymore.

My idea was to let Python open a browser tab and go to the www.instagram.com/p/ link but that also doesn't seem to work anymore.

I have no code to upload because it's all a big mess with different strategies so I just deleted it and decided to start over.

Comment: share your code and what did you try so far

Comment: I bet Instagram actively blocks random scripts from scrapping their site... Just a thought

Comment: I have no code to upload because it's all a big mess with different strategies so I just deleted it and decided to start over

Answer (score 0):

Just grab an https proxy list and here ya go, I wrote this a while back and can be easily edited to your needs.

```
import requests, sys, time
from random import choice
if len(sys.argv) < 2: sys.exit(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} <Post Link> <Proxy List>")


Comments = 0
ProxList = []
Prox = open(sys.argv[2], "r")readlines()
for line in ReadProx:
    ProxList.append(line.strip('\n'))

while True:
    try:
        g = requests.get(sys.argv[1], proxies={'https://': 'https://'+choice(ProxList)})
        print(g.json())
        time.sleep(5)
        if len(g.json()['data']['shortcode_media']['edge_liked_by']['count']) > Comments:
            print(f"[+] Like | {g.json()['data']['shortcode_media']['edge_liked_by']['edges'][int(Comments)]['node']['username']}")
            if len(g.json()['data']['shortcode_media']['edge_liked_by']['count']) == Comments - 1:
                pass
            else:
                Comments += 1
        time.sleep(1.5)     
    except KeyboardInterrupt: sys.exit("Done")
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```